# Catch a window close event from action script/flash

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

If this is a duplicate question I am sorry, it seems basic enough but could not find a proper answer.

The only way I have found so far to capture the **browser window close event** from actionscript/flash is actually to capture the event in javascript, and then use a javascript/flash data passing from the javascript callback.

Something around those lines:

```
window.onbeforeunload = clean_up;

function clean_up()
{
var flex = document.${application} || window.${application};
flex.myFlexFunction();
}
</SCRIPT>
```

and the flash part:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFlexFunction",cleanUp);

public function cleanUp():void{
  //your flash code here
}
```

Is this the proper way ? 
Are there other alternatives ?

Answer (score 3):

You can never catch the window close event from pure flash. That said, as far as I know, this is the proper way to handle this.